# Meaning of "to balance off"

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

What does "to balance off" mean in this sentence?

> And in the northeast, Wind’s solid-solid-broken balances off Thunder’s broken-broken-solid.

Comment: This would probably be easier to explain if you mention more of the context (a game?)

Answer (score 1):

According to a quick Google search, the phrase comes from ***101 Questions and Answers on Confucianism, Daoism, and Shinto*** by John Renard. The passage ([visible here](https://books.google.com/books?id=2fsCe699Ze8C&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=And%20in%20the%20northeast,%20Wind%E2%80%99s%20solid-solid-broken%20balances%20off%20Thunder%E2%80%99s%20broken-broken-solid.&source=bl&ots=upIzD1f8vM&sig=vWJ3VRFsVRDXpymHfKmnOKlL_7Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAmoVChMIlOSNjrnDxwIVSVs-Ch0ESwD8#v=onepage&q=And%20in%20the%20northeast%2C%20Wind%E2%80%99s%20solid-solid-broken%20balances%20off%20Thunder%E2%80%99s%20broken-broken-solid.&f=false)) is describing a religious diagram containing eight trigrams (sets of lines), such as can be seen in this image:
[image: Trigram diagram]

So, with all that out of the way (which was fun to research, if perhaps unnecessary), what does 'balances off' actually mean here? I would say that it has the same meaning as simply saying '*balances*' - the two trigrams, Thunder and Wind are placed opposite each other, and the assertion the author makes is probably that they complement or balance each other (or, perhaps, that the philosophical/religious concepts they *represent* balance each other).